# MDX Function (Excel PowerPivot) to Exclude Non Numeric Values from DB

Tags: mdx, powerpivot, cube

I am quite new to MDX and I am trying hard to write a query that allows me to retrieve only numeric values.

My query at present is:

```
SELECT NON EMPTY {ISNUMERIC([Measures].[Average Booking Window])} 
ON COLUMNS, NON EMPTY { 
               ([Stay Date].[Year].[Year].ALLMEMBERS * 
                [Stay Date].[Month of Year].[Month of Year].ALLMEMBERS ) 
            } DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_CAPTION, MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME 
              ON ROWS FROM ( 
                   SELECT ( [Booking Date].[Calendar].[Date].&[2018-01-01T00:00:00] : 
                            [Booking Date].[Calendar].[Date].&[2018-08-31T00:00:00] ) 
                   ON COLUMNS FROM ( 
                              SELECT ( { [Hotel].[Market].&[Pisa City, Italy] } ) 
                              ON COLUMNS 
                              FROM [MYCUBE])) 
                   WHERE ( [Hotel].[Market].&[Pisa City, Italy]) 
                           CELL PROPERTIES VALUE, BACK_COLOR, FORE_COLOR, 
                           FORMATTED_VALUE, FORMAT_STRING, FONT_NAME, FONT_SIZE,
                           FONT_FLAGS
```

The error I get is:
Query (1, 18) The  function expects a tuple set expression for the 1 argument. A string or numeric expression was used.

What I am expecting is to get data only when it's numeric and I want the MDX query to completely exclude the rows with non numeric data.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Have you verified if all the `(` are closed? It seems there is one `)` missing...

Comment: Hi Dalton, it looks like all the ( have been closed. I have just added the ( and ) after the ISNUMERIC. Before adding them, the query was working fine. Thanks

Comment: I think the problem is that `ISNUMERIC([Measures].[Average Booking Window]` returns `true` or `false`. You have to change this, maybe using a `filter`.